# Run t.test through a list of tibbles

Tags: r

```
structure(list(Species = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Caranxpapuensis","Caranxsexfasciatus", "Epinephelus merra", "Epinephelus polyphekadion", "Hipposcaruslongiceps", "Lethrinus nebulosus", "Lethrinus obsoletus", "Lethrinus olivaceus", "Lethrinusxanthochilus", "Lutjanus bohar", "Lutjanus fulvus", "Lutjanus gibbus", "Lutjanus kasmira", "Myripristis adusta", "Myripristis berndti", "Naso lituratus", "Naso unicornis", "Parupeneus barberinus", "Sargocentron spiniferum", "Siganus argenteus", "Sphyraena forsteri"), class = "factor"), Country = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("American Samoa", "Federated States of Micronesia", "Kiribati", "Marshall Islands", "NC"), class = "factor"), Kn = c(1.09219153997845, 0.79017036273396, 1.02547034006866, 1.11244965699788, 0.972280456514503, 0.971061586363312)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
Species = structure(2L, .Label = c("Caranx papuensis", "Caranx sexfasciatus", 
"Epinephelus merra", "Epinephelus polyphekadion", "Hipposcarus longiceps", 
"Lethrinus nebulosus", "Lethrinus obsoletus", "Lethrinus olivaceus", 
"Lethrinus xanthochilus", "Lutjanus bohar", "Lutjanus fulvus", 
"Lutjanus gibbus", "Lutjanus kasmira", "Myripristis adusta", 
"Myripristis berndti", "Naso lituratus", "Naso unicornis", 
"Parupeneus barberinus", "Sargocentron spiniferum", "Siganus argenteus", 
"Sphyraena forsteri"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

here is a fragment of my data (df.4).

I am trying to run a t.test between country within a given species.

I tried to use this piece of code:

```
df.38 <- split(df.4, list(df.4$Species),drop=TRUE) 
results<-lapply(df.38,t.test(Kn~Country,data=df.38))
```

But it returns this error message: Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
les arguments impliquent des nombres de lignes différents : 216, 354, 488, 3458, 820, 782, 271, 746, 963, 241, 260, 289

which basically means that the number of rows in my list (df.38) are different

Any help would be useful, thank you.

Comment: It looks that your error, is occurring, because you insert the original list (df.38) on the data argument of t.test, inside the lapply() function. This is not how you should use a lappy() loop. Should be something like this: lapply(df.38, function(x) t.test(Kn ~ Country, data = x))

Comment: it worked perfectly, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an incorrect syntax. Try something like this :

```
df.38 <- split(df.4, df.4$Species,drop=TRUE) 
results<-lapply(df.38, function(x) t.test(Kn~Country,data=x))
```